# How to copy book details from Calibre?

Tags: calibre

I would like to copy book information (at least book title and author) from Calibre using Ctrl + C into any text editor.

For example, the output could be like this: Charles Dickens - Great Expectations.

How to do it?

Comment: You can't. There's no option to copy the book information in the list of books in calibre.

Comment: I see. But maybe there are plugins to export book information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy: on the menu bar, select the *Convert Books* down-arrow (little triangle), select *Create a catalog of the books in your Calibre library*, and select the desired format and columns (and filter your list if desired). See http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/catalogs.html.